# Can't delete .plist files from Trash

Tags: macos, launchd, plist, trash

I have a program which, when deleting any app, also deletes the extra files and junk as well; including .plist files. Normally this works great though, this time around I've had a few files which won't allow me to empty the trash.

I get the following when I click on "Empty Trash":

> The operation can’t be completed because the item
>   “com.justinmind.prototyperfree.plist” is in use.
>
> The operation can’t be completed because the item
>   “com.marketcircle.Billings3.plist” is in use.
>
> The operation can’t be completed because the item
>   “com.opendns.osx.DNSCrypt-Menubar.plist” is in use.
>
> The operation can’t be completed because the item
>   “hewgill.com.Stack-Exchange-Notifier.plist” is in use.

I tried the following without success:

`launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.justinmind.prototyperfree.plist` and `launchctl unload /Users/myname/.Trash/com.justinmind.prototyperfree.plist`

Not sure how to stop these things so I can empty the trash. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

*OS X 10.9 (13A603)*

Comment: `rm -rf ~/.Trash/*` should do the work.

Answer (score 10):

When you have problems to empty the trash, `rm -rf ~/.Trash/*` in the terminal does the job for you.

Edit :

You have to keep in mind that there might be multiple `.Trash` directories. 
For example on a USB stick or a external Drive, OSX will create another `.Trash` at the root of the drive. So you might need to use  `rm -rf /Volumes/DriveName/.Trash.*`

Comment: Great, thanks Matthieu! This is a more direct way of deleting vs the solution I found in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If none of the other solutions work, you may have to turn off System Integrity Protection in Mac OS X.  This was a solution found suggested [on Apple Stack Exchange](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20505/how-to-add-characters-to-the-press-and-hold-character-picker-in-os-x-lion) as a method for editing the Keyboard-en.plist files for the Press-and-Hold Character Picker in OS X.  Their solution referenced MacWorld UK [here](https://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-turn-off-mac-os-x-system-integrity-protection-rootless-3638975/).  To do so:

- Reboot your Mac into Recovery Mode (Restart, hold ⌘-R until the Apple logo appears)
- When the OS X Utilities window appears, go to Utilities > Terminal
- Type `csrutil disable` and hit Enter
- Reboot your Mac
- Empty your trash.  The .plist files should disappear
- Reboot into Recovery Mode and this time enter `csrutil enable` into Terminal and then reboot again to resume System Integrity Protection on your Mac.

Comment: the only solution that worked for me, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I will continue running into this issue or not and or if this was the "correct" way of doing it though, the following worked to delete the files:

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/24122/33469

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue. It was an app that didn't exist/was corrupted and the description didn't help. For some reason, it seems that finder was using the file.

Preparation: open terminal and copy the following line (don't paste it yet): `sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash/*`

Step 1: relaunch finder

- `command+alt+esc`
- select finder and click "relaunch

Step 2 (immediately while this is happening): empty the trash

- Paste the above code into terminal (it should be copied already): sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash/*`
- you'll probably have to type in your password.

I did this except I used alfred to empty my trash and it worked.