# Repeated "styles" folder in trash

Tags: trash, macos, virus

I am having recurring "styles" folder inside my trash and when I try to delete it, it is showing "the operation cannot be completed because the item "styles" is in use! Is this a virus?

[image]

Comment: What is the root folder inside trash that all these styles folders are located in?

Comment: @IronCraftMan it starts with "styles" ....... not sure how it ends  ..... downloaded clamxav and scanning now

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113501/cant-delete-plist-files-from-trash?rq=1) by [Matthieu Riegler](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/21416/matthieu-riegler) suggests the following when dealing with a Trash that won't empty (this does not, however, address WHAT the files are or whether they are malicious):

---

When you have problems to empty the trash, `rm -rf ~/.Trash/*` in the terminal does the job for you.

You have to keep in mind that there might be multiple .Trash directories. 
For example on a USB stick or a external Drive, OSX will create another .Trash at the root of the drive. So you might need to use  `rm -rf /Volumes/DriveName/.Trash.*`